# Creating and appending google charts on the fly to the divs created dynamically in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I have the following code, in which I iterate through a list of items and create dynamic div elements. Then, at the end of each loop, I want to create a barchart using `google visualisations` and append it to the `divs` created. However, I receive the following error.

> Container is not defined

I am new to `google visualisations`. I wonder if this is possible. Below is my code:

```
function drawBarChart() {

    PAGES = _.keys(_.countBy(perct_by_page_COLL_vs_NCOLL, function(data) { return data.PAGE_SHORT; }));

    $.each(PAGES, function(index, item){
        $("#BLOQUES").append("<div class='" + item + "'></div>")
        page_sub = $.grep(perct_by_page_COLL_vs_NCOLL, function(n, i) {return n.PAGE_SHORT === item;});

        container = $("#BLOQUES").find('.' + item)

        container.append('<div>' + page_sub[0].PAGE_TITLE + '</div>')
        container.append("<div class='barchart'></div>")

        x = page_sub[0]
        a = x['PAGE_SHORT']
        b = x['PERC_ALL']
        c = x['PERC_NCOLL']
        d = x['PERC_ALL']

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['PAGE_SHORT', 'PERC_ALL', 'PERC_COLL', 'PERC_NCOLL'], [a, b, c, d]
        ]);

        var options = {
            title: '',
            chartArea: {width: '50%'},
            hAxis: {
              title: 'Total Population',
              minValue: 0
            },
            vAxis: {
              title: 'City'
            }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(container.find('.barchart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the chart is expecting a specific dom element
not a jquery reference, which is basically an array of elements

recommend using the loop index to assign an id to the chart element

```
container.append("<div id='chart" + index + "' class='barchart'></div>")
```

then using the id to create the chart

```
var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart($('#chart' + index)[0]);
```

full snippet...

```
function drawBarChart() {

  PAGES = _.keys(_.countBy(perct_by_page_COLL_vs_NCOLL, function(data) { return data.PAGE_SHORT; }));

  $.each(PAGES, function(index, item){
    $("#BLOQUES").append("<div class='" + item + "'></div>")
    page_sub = $.grep(perct_by_page_COLL_vs_NCOLL, function(n, i) {return n.PAGE_SHORT === item;});

    container = $("#BLOQUES").find('.' + item)

    container.append('<div>' + page_sub[0].PAGE_TITLE + '</div>')
    container.append("<div id='chart" + index + "' class='barchart'></div>")

    x = page_sub[0]
    a = x['PAGE_SHORT']
    b = x['PERC_ALL']
    c = x['PERC_NCOLL']
    d = x['PERC_ALL']

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['PAGE_SHORT', 'PERC_ALL', 'PERC_COLL', 'PERC_NCOLL'], [a, b, c, d]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: '',
        chartArea: {width: '50%'},
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Total Population',
          minValue: 0
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'City'
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart($('#chart' + index)[0]);
    chart.draw(data, options);

  });
}
```